# Java JOptionPane Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.9.4.

To help with GUI building I have downloaded the windows builder tool for eclipse.

I would like to press a button and have a popup display some text so I have imported the required packages and done the following:

```
btnSignIn = new Button(shlUserSignIn, SWT.NONE);
        btnSignIn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
            }
        });
```

This produces the following error and causes the program to crash:

```
2014-08-02 19:36:46.459 java[32273:507] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
2014-08-02 19:36:48.067 java[32273:507] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2014-08-02 19:36:48.068 java[32273:507] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
2014-08-02 19:36:48.593 java[32273:16303] *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7fff1b7c96a0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2014-08-02 19:36:48.593 java[32273:16303] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2014-08-02 19:36:48.696 java[32273:16303] *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7fff1b097ee0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2014-08-02 19:36:48.696 java[32273:16303] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2014-08-02 19:36:48.798 java[32273:16303] *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7fff1b0984b0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2014-08-02 19:36:48.798 java[32273:16303] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2014-08-02 19:36:48.901 java[32273:16303] *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7fff1b7cd5a0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2014-08-02 19:36:48.901 java[32273:16303] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2014-08-02 19:36:49.002 java[32273:16303] *** -[NSConditionLock unlock]: lock (<NSConditionLock: 0x7fff1b0981c0> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2014-08-02 19:36:49.002 java[32273:16303] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

After doing some research I have found that the first error isn't serious until the method is made redundant. I can't find a solution to the `Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode` or `NSConditionLock unlock`errors.

What is the problem? I'm 100% sure the syntax is fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Button instead of JButton?

Comment: You seem to be using lots of native OSX  components (Class name starts with NS) in a Java application.  I'd recommend using only swing  components,  especially in a swing container.

Comment: Also, what did you construct the UI out of? Window builder generates swing code last I checked.

Comment: @AndrewG To my knowledge all I did was install window builder and create a swing project and this is my outcome. The code was created for me when you drag the button control onto the form, I didn't get a choice.

Comment: Hmm.  I've spent a lot of time working with swing and window builder,  never seen it work with objects out of the cocoa framework or with a selection listener.

Comment: Could you post more of your code so I can see context? Preferably the code generated by your plug-in.